# Terasort scheduler in Hadoop

Tags: sorting, hadoop, scheduler

In the Hadoop's implementation of Terasort, there's a scheduler called TeraScheduler. Having read through the code, the scheduler basically does the following:

1. Pick the host with smallest number of splits
2. For this host, pick a fixed number of splits with the smallest number of hosts and "pin" them to be executed on this host. The "unchosen" splits are removed from this host.
3. Repeat for all hosts.

I don't understand the rationale behind this schedule. How does it perform better than the default scheduler (what is the default scheduler, anyway)? Is there any paper explaining its benefits?

Answer (score 2):

The benefits are two folds:
(1) to make sort local as much as possible.
(2) distribute the work evenly across machine

Both aims to improve the performance.